# регулярное выражение (re) для строки на русском языке: найти три буквенно-цифровых символа с последующей точкой

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, кодировка, unicode, python-2.7

Python 2.7.6 
проблема с применением re к строке на русском.

1. задача - найти три буквенно-цифровых символа с последующей точкой;
2. код:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
   import re
   new = re.findall("\w{3}\.", "gth. Ср. дек.  7 21:22:29 EET 2016" )
   print new
   ```
3. результат >> `['gth.']`
4. вопрос: почему игнорируется `'дек.'`?

Comment: 3 "буквенно-цифровых символа" *включая* `_`? `\w` находит символы подчеркивания. А ответ Алекса верен: в 2.7 надо использовать `re.U` / `u""`.

Comment: Спасибо, ведь действительно  \w включает _. В моем случае не критично, но я не вспомнил это.

Comment: Символ подчёркивания исключается вот так - `[^\W_]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте Unicode-строки и флаг re.UNICODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-*

import re
pattern = re.compile(ur"\w{3}\.", re.UNICODE)
match = pattern.findall(u"gth. Ср. дек.  7 21:22:29 EET 2016")
print(match)
for i in match:
    print(i)
```

Результат:

```
[u'gth.', u'\u0434\u0435\u043a.']
gth.
дек.
```